# correctness of json document for elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, json

I am new for Json Document,i hava database with the following fileds:

[image]

On the basis of database field i have created Json document:

================================================================

```
{"Id":["fifth","first","four","second","thrid"],"keyword":["michel","sam","jerry","John","smith"]}
```

================================================================

I just want to know that the prepared `json` document is correct for elastic search or not? if wrong then what will be correct document for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is good. You should create json in following format.

```
var data = {
    "fifth" : "michel",
    "first" : "sam",
    "four" : "jerry",
    "second" : "John",
    "thrid" : "smith"
}
```

So when you need to get the fourth element, so can just get it by following

```
var fourth = data["four"];
```

**hope this helps!**